# Espressif ESP32 web server HTML example

Tags: html, mongoose, xxd, esp32

I'm working on an embedded ESP32 design using one of the web server examples included in the esp-idf examples. I'm able to get the device into soft AP mode and display a simple web page. Now that I have that working, I'm trying to build a page with a graphic.

I'm using the Linux hex tool "xxd -i  " to convert the HTML file into a hex dump array for the C include file. It works fine if the document is just HTML, but I'm stuck on trying to do this with an image.

I went as far as using xxd on both the HTML file and the image file and using "netconn_write" to write out both files. I also tried combining them into a single hex dump file. At this point I'm not sure how to proceed, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this utility](https://gist.github.com/cpq/4714740) to embed any number of binary files in your executable. Don't forget to set a correct mime type. Also, if the file is big, you have to rate limit the sending, which might become a non-trivial task.

Therefore I suggest to use a filesystem and an embedded web server to do the job. Take a look at https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose-os/tree/master/fw/examples/mjs_hello (disclaimer: I am one of the developers). It'll take you few minutes to get a firmware with working HTTP server, ready for you prototypes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll look this over and try to embed a filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use de directive EMBED_FILES directly in `CMakeLists.txt`. For example, to add the file `favicon.jpg` image, in my `CMakeLists.txt`, in the same directory of `main.c`:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
  INCLUDE_DIRS "."
  EMBED_FILES "favicon.jpg")
```

And somewhere in the main.c:

```
/* The favicon */
static esp_err_t favicon_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    extern const char favicon_start[] asm("_binary_favicon_jpg_start");
    extern const char favicon_end[] asm("_binary_favicon_jpg_end");
    size_t favicon_len = favicon_end - favicon_start;

    httpd_resp_set_type(req, "image/jpeg");
    httpd_resp_send(req, favicon_start, favicon_len);

    return ESP_OK;
}

static const httpd_uri_t favicon_uri = {
                                         .uri       = "/favicon.ico",
                                         .method    = HTTP_GET,
                                         .handler   = favicon_handler,
                                         .user_ctx  = NULL
};
```

You can add as many files you need in this way, text, html, json, etc... (respecting device memory, of course).